# Name that Movie (part III)

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-crosswords

In the spirit of thirds, this list is a list clues that roughly name movies that are each the first of a trilogy.

1.

```
Not your breakfast cereal
```

2.

```
Oakland helps out Moses
```

3.

```
The latest addition to late comedian Bob's family tree
```

Hint:

> Some pedants may refute the "triloginess" of some.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1:** Not your breakfast cereal

> The Matrix (They're My Trix) 
>  (from LogicianWithAHat's answer)

**2:** Oakland helps out Moses:

> Raiders of the Lost Ark (Indiana Jones)
>  -- Oakland = Raiders (NFL team), and Moses built the Ark of the Covenant

**3:** The latest addition to late comedian Bob's family tree

> A New Hope (Star Wars)
>  -- Bob Hope is a late comedian, and New is the latest addition

Comment: I might be one of those pedants that will refute the "triloginess" of Indiana Jones :)

Comment: I thought it was common agreement that the last one doesn't count :P

Comment: 2/3 gets the checkmark, I guess. @LogicianWithAHat filled in the missing one.

Answer (score 5):

**1:** Not your breakfast cereal

> The Matrix (They're My Trix)

The 'trilogy-ness' of this one is also in dispute

Comment: *groan* I looked at that cereal specifically and didn't see this stretch :)

Comment: I guess that's why they aren't "your" cereal :(

Comment: Matrix is totally a trilogy - there's the "I know kung fu" one, there's the one with the Merovingian fight, and there's that weird collection-of-shorts animated one. Three. :D